# Need an interpretation on a statistical expression on missing values

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, missing-data, imputation

I was reading a paper about missing values on the Internet and having a problem in interpreting interpreting the meaning of the first sentence highlighted in bold below:

Missing data present various problems. ***First, the absence of data reduces statistical power, which refers to the probability that the test will reject the null hypothesis when it is false***. Second, the lost data can cause bias in the estimation of parameters. Third, it can reduce the representativeness of the samples. Fourth, it may complicate the analysis of the study. Each of these distortions may threaten the validity of the trials and can lead to invalid conclusions.

Hope to hear some explanations.

Comment: Please use SO for programming questions only. This kind of question would fit better on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I didn't realize when posting.

Comment: No worries, it happens all the time. I just let people know that there are dedicated SE sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Firstly***, power is the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when in fact it is false. So, you could say it is the probability of making the correct decision. The absence of data reduces this statistical power, a low sample size of studies, small effects being investigated, or both adversely impacts the likelihood that a statistically significant finding actually reflects a true effect. Meaning let's say if you've 100 samples and because of missing values you discard 40 samples from the dataset, now whatever conclusion you come up with using the remaining 60 samples, you can't be much confident that it reflects a true effect.

***Secondly***, If you choose to replace those missing values using the mean for example, then you're injecting a sort of bias to the data, actually, however you decide to replace or remove the data, the bias is getting injected. (though certain bias is more plausible in certain situations)

***Thirdly***, the sentence is quite explanatory itself, those missing values reduce the representativeness of the samples, as you don't have all the info you need about those samples.

***Lastly***, we can say it (missing values) actually does complicates our study, It's the last thing we would want when working with data, however because of human error and many other sources of errors we often have to deal with these missing values with certain operations.